# Android show dialog when screen is off

Tags: android

am working on an android project but my issues is changing the dialog when the phone goes to sleep. Here is the scenario, the user taps a button that shows a dialog processing while the application connects to server, if the communication takes long the phone may sleep during this process so i want when the user wakes up the phone the dialog may have changed to transaction successful or something like that. Please help, Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use [WakeLock](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) until your transaction completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onStart()` or `onResume()` callbacks of `Activity` or `Fragment` to update your Dialog.

Comment: The server connection is handled by a service which sends a broadcast to the activity to update the dialog accordingly, am not even sure when the broadcast is received when the phone is sleeping, give me more insights

Comment: You will have to save the success or failure somewhere, like in SharedPref. Because you won't be able to receive the Broadcast, once you have unregistered it.

Comment: @odichdaniel, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. BTW there is no obligation to do this.